# Avoiding cyclic dependency in JSON schema definition

Tags: json, jsonschema

How do you define two fields that refer to one another without causing a cyclic dependency.

In the following example I would like the maximum of min_percentage to be the minimum of max_percentage, and the minimum of max_percentage to be the maximum of min_percentage;

So

```
"min_percentage": {

    "type": "integer",
    "minimum" : 1,
    "maximum" : 99
}

"max_percentage": {

    "type": "integer",
    "minimum" : 2,
    "maximum" : 150
}
```

becomes something like

```
"min_percentage": {

    "type": "integer",
    "minimum" : 1,
    "maximum" : "#max_percentage#minimum"
}

"max_percentage": {

    "type": "integer",
    "minimum" : "#min_percentage#maximum",
    "maximum" : 150
}
```

EDIT: I THOUGHT A POSSIBLE SOLUTION WOULD BE..

This may be possible using Schema Dependencies
https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html?highlight=default

We only specify max_percentage, and make min_percentage a dependency, then #min_percentage#maximum can be based on #max_percentage#minimum removing any cyclic dependency.

```
    "max_percentage": {

        "type": "integer",
        "minimum" : 2,
        "maximum" : 150
    }

    "dependencies": {

        "max_percentage": {

            "properties": {

                "min_percentage": {

                    "type": "integer",
                    "minimum" : 1,
                    "maximum" : "#max_percentage#minimum"
                }
            },
            "required": ["min_percentage"]
        }
    }
```

BUT APPARENTLY THIS CANNOT BE DONE..
[Can JSON integer attributes be referenced?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171993/can-json-integer-attributes-be-referenced/45210932#45210932)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In acyclic graphs you can always find a [Topological sorting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Equally important, this also holds the other way around. This can be applied here by thinking of each reference as a directed edge in a directed graph where each node is some variable in your document.

What that tells us is that it should be possible to list all values in such a manner that we only ever need to refer back, and never refer to an element listed further down in the document if our depedencies are acyclic. This of course comes at a cost, as it is not guaranteed that such a list will still be able to follow the same grouping. But here is a possible format with the aforementioned list format:

```
"min_max_percentage": 30
"min_percentage": {

    "type": "integer",
    "minimum" : 1,
    "maximum" : "#min_max_percentage"
}

"max_percentage": {

    "type": "integer",
    "minimum" : "#min_max_percentage",
    "maximum" : 150
}
```

As is guaranteed by topological sorting, you will always be able to find such a representation by introducing additional 'proxy variables' such as `min_max_percentage` as long as your depedency graph is acyclic. And, conversely, if your format specification only allows backreferences then will never have a cyclic dependency.

Comment: But wouldn't this limit both min_percentage#maximum and max_percentage#minimum to min_max_percentage? If so, I didn't want to do that as these can change.

If this were code we could make min_max_percentage take on the value of the first item set, i.e. if max_percentage#minimum was set first, this would be its new value and reflect on the setting of min_percentage#maximum. The trick is to get the schema to do this during the validation of the JSON, any ideas?

Comment: JSON is not code though, it's rather meant for __efficient__ object __notation__. If you were to try to represent a fully blown relational model, you are probably better off with using something like XML which has much better support for what I think that you want to achieve, after this comment. Notably, it features `DOM` (Document Object Model) and thus references and can also do `Schema validation`.